# Positioning text with word-space on desktop and mobile device css

Tags: html, css

It works good on desktop devise, but i wanr for mobile make each sentence in a column. How can i make it with css? I  dont want to use flex  or another blocks.

```css
.hero__subtitle {
    word-spacing: 5em;
  }
```

```html
<p class="hero__subtitle">
               Some text for test. Another text for test.  Another text for test.
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use flex?

Comment: @MasterYoda its  a user input in my case. So its  uncomfortablet o divide into blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media query for making different display for different devices . if you don't know about media query just search a little it just works with the given pixels. Or you can use js to split the given string to its words or its sentences and print even in different H1 tags. Or tags with custom classes. Depends on your imagination

Comment: I know it, i  am just trying to make it without dividing text into sentences and diffrent tags. But there is no such way, i think.

Comment: in js or in css you will just tell it when show yourself different. and if you want it to be shown different. have to use a backend language or js . js can help u much about it. but u can also do that one. give a div and children in it . these children will contain the sentences you want. and give css to the parent. then just use media querry to give css to the children of the parent. and give !important to end of every css for css to understand it must be done instead of parent's css